# BAD UDP LENGTH > IP PAYLOAD LENGTH (WIRESHARK) - WHY?

Tags: networking, udp, ip, wireshark, fpga

I am working on FPGA ETHERNET project. My problem is following :a UDP/IP packet sent from FPGA is captured by "wireshark" and it gives me a following warning : "BAD UDP LENGTH 26 > IP PAYLOAD LENGTH Len=18 (Malformed Packet)".
[BAD_UDP_LENGTH(PICTURE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj7if.jpg)

Actually, I am trying to send the following packet :
55555555555555D598EECB9B6EF400123456789008004500002EB3FE0000801108BDA9FE1504A9FE1503FA00FA00001A45630 **00102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F1011** 06A07518

You can see that the last byte of data is **11** and that part of data is not displayed by "wireshark".  **That part of data is obviously transmitted** as I have seen it on oscilloscope. I have tried  the number of different Ethernet Packet generators(PacketETH,EthernetUDP,C#) and all of them have generated the same packets (I think no problem lies in packet or packet generators). Also I have captured packets by different network monitoring software "Omnipeek" which gave me the same result as gave "wireshark"  : **LAST BYTE IS NOT DISPLAYED**

If the last byte displayed, I think  "wireshark" wouldn't  give me that error.

Does anybody know how to solve that problem ?

```
Here I will give you additional details :
```

1) I am using  [Digilent Anvyl FPGA](https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/anvyl:anvyl_rm.pdf?_ga=2.87615128.1447520814.1585026975-1792992917.1575934537) which has  [LAN8720A-CP-TR](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/312187/SMSC/LAN8720A-CP-TR.html) tranceiver. I have written code in VHDL and also run simulation in ISIM which gave me a correct result, concretely:  ***all bits are sent successively with relevant values***. Besides, I have checked simulation result in reality by probing LAN8720A-CP-TR tranceiver transmit pins by  [Digilent Electronics Explorer](https://store.digilentinc.com/electronics-explorer-all-in-one-usb-oscilloscope-multimeter-workstation-limited-time/)

2) For Ethernet packet generation I am using a simple program which you can download from here [EthernetUDP](https://www.fpga4fun.com/10BASE-T2.html) (fpga4fun.com) here is picture of packet generated by that program   [EthernetUDP picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq76u.png)

Comment: Well, you've created a malformed packet.  If I copy the frame data from the image, I get this:

0000  98 ee cb 9b 6e f4 00 12 34 56 78 90 08 00 45 00
0010  00 2e b3 fe 00 00 80 11 08 bd a9 fe 15 04 a9 fe
0020  15 03 fa 00 fa 00 00 1a 45 63 00 01 02 03 04 05
0030  06 07 08 09 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 11
0040

Answer (score 0):

If I copy the frame data from the image, I get this:

```
0000  98 ee cb 9b 6e f4 00 12 34 56 78 90 08 00 45 00
0010  00 2e b3 fe 00 00 80 11 08 bd a9 fe 15 04 a9 fe
0020  15 03 fa 00 fa 00 00 1a 45 63 00 01 02 03 04 05
0030  06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 11
0040
```

And if I save that in a file called packet.txt then run `text2pcap packet.txt packet.pcap`, then load the resulting capture file back into Wireshark, I get a completely valid packet including the trailing 0x11 byte and the "bytes on wire" is indicated as 60 bytes instead of 59 bytes.

So somehow in your setup, that last byte didn't get handed off to Wireshark; therefore it simply wasn't captured for some reason, which is the reason why it's not displayed.  Why it wasn't captured is an open question.  It may have been transmitted as you say, since you can see it on the oscilloscope, but *something* about it or your capture hardware isn't correct.